# Read binary file splitting chunks by separator in python

Tags: python, binary, readfile

I have a binary file and I want to print chunks where chunks size is variable. Each chunk is separated by hexadecimal number `3E47`.

In Ruby I can "separate" the chunks with the sentence `BEGIN{....}` in the script below.

How would be the way to do it in Python?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -E BINARY
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

BEGIN { $/="\3e\x47".force_encoding("BINARY") }
IO.foreach(ARGV[0]) { |l|     
    chunk = l.unpack('H*')[0]       
    puts chunk
} if File.exists?(ARGV[0])
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code translation service.  Show us the Python you've written so far and the part you're stuck on, and maybe we can help.

Comment: Hey Kevin. I know. The part I'm stuck is in the BEGIN {...} sentence. I don't have a code for this since I don't have idea. Do you know the equivalent for this in python?